# Installing scrapy on pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pycharm

I'm trying to install Scrapy on Pycharm but it keeps giving me the following error:

command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

I've got the 2019 vs build tools installed too, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you may want to try upgrading your `pip` using the following command:
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Afterwards, try the following:
`pip install Scrapy`
or
`pip3 install Scrapy`

If those don't work, try what's listed below.

Based on the information found here: [Installing Scappy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html), it seems like they recommend you install Anaconda or Miniconda:

> Though it’s possible to install Scrapy on Windows using pip, we recommend you to install Anaconda or Miniconda and use the package from the conda-forge channel, which will avoid most installation issues.

It says once you install either Anaconda or Miniconda, you can run the following command to install Scrappy:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Created a project with Conda and it worked so thanks !

Comment: @MohSameh No worries, glad it helped